# Get data from API using Python and load into Azure SQL Data Warehouse using Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a Data Warehouse in Azure that contains information from several sources. The input data comes from diferent APIS, which I want to access them using python and the output should be stored into the Warehouse. This process should be updated every day.

I have read lots of documents from Azure, but I can't understand how I need to design this process.

The first question is: Where should the python processes, to collect the data from the different APIs, be created? In a pipeline of the Azure Data Factory or somewhere else?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Data Factory, you would connect to the sources using the built-in connectors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

By using the V2 service in ADF, you would be able to schedule the pipeline to trigger daily at your desired times.

Comment: But there is no connector to the services I want to use, so I think that I should code a python script to get the data (using APIs) and then save it to Azure Data Lake or to a container as a blobl storage. My question is, in which location should I write the python script?

Comment: Are those sources REST endpoints? You could use the HTTP data source in that case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http

Answer (score 0):

With python you can use the API to create, configure and schedule the data factory pipelines. There won't be any python code running, data factory is configured only with json files. The Python library will only help you to create these json files in a language you are familiar with, the same goes for .net, powershell and every other supported language. The end result is always a bunch of json files.

I dont know the specifics for your case, but in general you need to create linked services, datasets (that will use those linked services), and pipelines that will be a group of logical activities (that will make use of those datasets).

If you are using ADFv1, you can configure the schedule within the dataset's properties and you wont need a gateway as you are not using on-premise data. If you are using ADFv2, you will need an Azure Integration Runtime (type "managed") and you can configure the schedule with triggers.

I hope I was able to clarify a bit these concepts.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Throw away your Python code and define an [HTTP Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http) to describe your data movement. You are also probably going to need a subsequent transformation activity for the "Transform" step of your ETL.
2. Embed your Python code into a [custom activity run by Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compute-linked-services#azure-batch-linked-service). This is a pretty harder and error prone solution.

In your position, I'd go with the HTTP Connector.